# HorizontalHeader with QCheckBox in cell 0

Tags: c++, qt5, qtablewidget

How to add a HorizontalHeader with a checkbox in the first index (cell 0) to a QTableWidget in Qt?
Below instructions did not work.

```
headerItem->setFlags(headerItem->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable);
headerItem->data(Qt::CheckStateRole);
headerItem->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
qTableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,headerItem);
```

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

you can set another flag, see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum):

```
headerItem->setFlags(headerItem->flags() ^ Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
```

That was my first thought. After several tries and research in documentation and several fora i am quite sure, that items in QheaderView don't support checkboxes.

But You can set different icons to the headerItem in dependance of (pseudo-)checkstate and save the checkstate if necassary in `headerItem.data(userRole)`. I did it in the following steps (i only know Python, but i think, you can translate it to C++):

set the icon:

```
headerItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('unchecked.png'))
headerItem.setData(256,'unchecked')
headerItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
```

connect signal

```
self.horizontalHeader().sectionClicked.connect(self.changeIcon)
```

and define the method to change the icons

```
def changeIcon(self,index):
    if self.horizontalHeaderItem(index).data(256) == 'unchecked':
        self.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('checked.png'))
        self.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setData(256,'checked')
    else:
        self.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('unchecked.png'))
        self.horizontalHeaderItem(index).setData(256,'unchecked')
```

that's the result:

[image: unchecked]

[image: and checked]

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass `QHeaderView` reimplement the `paintSection( )` and `mousePressEvent( )` methods and of course draw the rectangle for the clickable part and keep in mind that when resizing occurs you'll have to redraw the whole thing + clickable area.

I wouldn't know about another possible way other than maybe abusing the `cornerWidget` of the `QTableWidget`.

Take a look at the `QPainter` and `QMouseEvent` classes.

---

Well a dirty way could be to just reserve `row( 0 )` for this kind of stuff where you can use `setCellWidget( )`

Comment: I tried setCellWidget but did'nt work for HorizontalHeader, of course with this property I add a checkbox to rows (     qTableWidget->setCellWidget(row,0, check); )
.

Comment: yeah but it won't work for the header only proper way is to subclass as I wrote